# Set default lang using php

Tags: php, default, lang

I'm trying to set a multilungal website using cookie. Everything's fine but I'm having trouble setting a default language. 
I'm getting an error "undefined index" in php when i get to the root website without parameter.

```
<?php
if (isset ($_COOKIE['CHOIXlang']) && $_GET['langue'] != 'fr' && $_GET['langue'] != 'en' && $_GET['langue'] != 'es') 
{           
$langue = $_COOKIE['CHOIXlang'];
}
else if ($_GET['langue'] == 'en' || $_GET['langue'] == 'fr' || $_GET['langue'] == 'es')
{ 
$langue = $_GET['langue'];
set_cookie($langue);
}
else            
{
$langue = substr($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);
set_cookie($langue);
}
?>

<?php
function set_cookie($langue)
{

$expire = 365*24*3600;

if (setcookie("CHOIXlang", $langue, time() + $expire) != TRUE)
    {

    }
else
    {
    setcookie("CHOIXlang", $langue, time() + $expire);

    }
}
?>
```

And in the body :

```
<?php 

if ($_GET['langue'] == "fr" || $langue == "fr") 
{
    include('lang/fr-lang.php');
}
elseif ($_GET['langue'] == "en" || $langue == "en")
{
    include('lang/en-lang.php');
} 
elseif ($_GET['langue'] == "es" || $langue == "es")
{
    include('lang/es-lang.php');
} 


?>
```

What did I miss to set default language when the website opens ?

Thank you

Comment: which array index causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if your get parameter langue is set: `isset($_GET['langue'])`

```
<?php 

if (!isset($_GET['langue'])
{
    include('lang/default-lang.php');
}
elseif ($langue == "fr") 
{
    include('lang/fr-lang.php');
}
elseif ($langue == "en")
{
    include('lang/en-lang.php');
} 
elseif ($langue == "es")
{
    include('lang/es-lang.php');
} 
?>
```

Also in you need to change this line : `$langue = $_GET['langue'];` to this:

```
if (isset($_GET['langue']))
   $langue = $_GET['langue'];
```

**UPDATE**

You cannot access any GET value that does not exist. First you need to check if it was set. `isset($_GET['langue'])` returns true if the parameter was set, so just use this check once at the beginning of your code.
I'd suggest this:

```
$langue = "";
if (!isset($_GET['langue']){
    $langue = $_GET['langue'];
}
```

then use only `$langue` instead of `$_GET['langue']`.

Comment: well i tried this, but still i'm getting error saying i have undefined index: langue

Comment: and apparently the problem is coming from the first line of my code

Comment: You cannot access any GET value that does not exist. First you need to check if it was set. `isset($_GET['langue'])` return `true` if the parameter was set, so just use this check once at the beginning of your code.

Comment: pk i got this fixed finaly thanks i needed to check my parameter indeed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set Default Lan may should be like this

```
if (@$_GET['lang'] == 'en') include('en-lang.php');
else include('fr-lang.php');
```

Use  $_GET for it:

This is a little long winded but might be a slightly better approach:

```
<?php 

session_start(); 

if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) $lang = $_SESSION['lang']; 

if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
     $lang = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $_GET['lang']);
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang; 
}

if (!isset($lang)) $lang = 'fr'; 
$langfile = $lang . '-lang.php'; 

if (file_exists($langfile)) include ($langfile); 
else include('fr-lang.php');

?>
```